# Lorentz equations in the reference orbit coordinate system

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, reference-frames

The equations of motion of a charged particle in a electromagnetic field is determined by the Lorentz force equations.

Let's suppose I have a charged particle in a constant magnetic field coming out of the page, so the particle will describe a circle on the page.

Using Cartesian coordinates I can calculate the distance that the particle travels for some time $t$ if I solve the equations of motion for $x$ and $y$ (coordinates of the page). However, if my system is at the reference orbit, I just need to solve the Lorentz equations for some longitudinal coordinate $\theta$.

How would the Lorentz equations be in that reference system? I would also like to generalize for cases where there are electric fields and the particle does not start exactly at the reference orbit.

Comment: Maybe a surface of revolution in a "warped" product space $M=B\times_{f} F$ where the leaves are different positions of the of the rotated curve and the fibers are circles of revolution. The function $f$ is the warping function for metrics on the product space. The curve is a projection of $\alpha(s)=(\beta(s),\theta(s))$ onto $B$ and $F$. Unfortunately, I don't anything about them. Try https://math.stackexchange.com.